# How do I get started if I want to use PostgreSQL for local use?

Tags: postgresql, local

Good day,

Currently I use MS Access at home for several Databases (for personal use).

At work, I use PostgreSQL, which is infinity times better. I want to start using postgres for my personally used databases, but I don't know where to start.

I've tried reading the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-start.html), but still don't know how to start. I don't have a server at home; is it possible I can just make a `local database/tablespace`? Or would I have to host a virtual server?

*Note that I am willing to use other open source databases if there is an easy option out there - MS access is just so... terrible.*

Thanks,

Comment: Use [Windows installers](http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/).

Comment: Installing Postgresql in local machine is easy as like other db's. Download the installer based on your OS from http://www.postgresql.org/ downloads section. While installing remember the portno and password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it seems you have Windows at home. You just need to download full installer for PostgreSQL:
http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/

After installation it will automatically add starting postgres server as a service on local machine. That means, server will always run in background, but you can disable that later, or just uninstall.

After that, you can use pgAdmin (included in default installation package) or other client tools to access the DB engine.

**UPD** in pgadmin, create connection with this settings:

1. 'localhost' as hostname;
2. port - 5432;
3. user, database - postgres (for testing purpose only - you should create your own user and tables with restricted rights later).
4. Password for postgres (that is DB admin user) must be entered during installation process.

Server settings are stored somewhere here:
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\data"

1. pg_hba.conf - Client Authentication Configuration File
2. postgresql.conf - Configuration File

Comment: You may also find OpenOffice.Org Base interesting, though it's pretty clunky and limited. It has a form designer of sorts, and a vaguely usable report designer.